# how to use scope_identity in visual studio 2005?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, scope-identity

Where to put the `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` statement if I want to get the last inserted identity, I put it inside other insert into query but I get nothing..

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

connection.Open();

string insACmd = "insert into admin (userName, password) values (@userName, @password) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
SqlCommand insertAdmin = new SqlCommand(insACmd, connection);

insertAdmin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", TextBox1.Text);
insertAdmin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text);

string insertedID = insertAdmin.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

connection.Close();
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing - but this works just fine in my case. Do you get an error? If so: what error? What return value do you get in `insertedID` - `NULL`? empty string? Something else?

Comment: I inserted that code inside try block and inside catch I have an error message so when I run my website I got that error message also I noticed that nothing inserted into my DB

Comment: **WHAT** is that error message?? I can't see your screen - you need to tell us what the error is!!

Comment: Don't you need a semicolon after the insert statement? It looks like the insert and select are on the same line with no statement terminator

Comment: Charleh I tried to put semicolon but the problem still occur..

Comment: marc_s it is just an error that I typed inside catch block, I thought that my explanation is clear

Comment: Did you check this **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11176770/1451723)**?

Answer (score 0):

try this `

> SELECT UserId=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

that is if you are using UserId, as the key

Comment: do you mean to put it instead of the current select scope_identity statement or as another query?

Comment: try replacing your current select scope and specify the ID you want to retrieve with this one

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    string insACmd = "insert into admin (userName, password) values (@userName, @password); DECLARE @ID INT OUTPUT; SET @ID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
    using (SqlCommand insertAdmin = new SqlCommand(insACmd, connection))
    {
        insertAdmin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", TextBox1.Text);
        insertAdmin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text);

        SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter();
        p.ParameterName = "@ID";
        p.Size = 4;
        p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        insertAdmin.Parameters.Add(p);
        insertAdmin.ExecuteNonQuery();
        int idOut = (int)p.Value;
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Kanavi,                                                       i I think you are using VB and I actually use C# can you please tell me how to write this sentence  DECLARE @ID INT OUTPUT; SET @ID=SCOPE_IDENTITY() in C# because I am novice in both asp.net and VB